# React adding custom props to vanilla html elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
      const handleChange = (e) => {
          console.log(e.target.id);
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
          <option value="1-10" id="foo">
            1-10
          </option>
```

How can I make the `id` prop in the `<option>` tag accessible by the code above? `e.target.id` returns nothing, but `e.target.value` returns the selected value. How can I create these custom attributes with when using vanilla html elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest method to achieve this is as follows:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const index = e.target.selectedIndex;
    const id = e.target.childNodes[index].id;
    console.log(id); // logs 'foo' or 'bar' depending on selection
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
        <option value="1-10" id="foo">
          1-10
        </option>
        <option value="11-20" id="bar">
          11-20
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

`e.target` is the `select`, not the `option`. And since the `select` does not have an `id`, you are getting nothing. One way to achieve what you want is by doing so :

```js
export default function App() {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const selectedOption = e.target.querySelector(`option[value='${e.target.value}']`);
    console.log(selectedOption.id);
  };
  return (
    <select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
      <option value="1-10" id="foo">
        1-10
      </option>
      <option value="1-11" id="bar">
        1-11
      </option>
    </select>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do so

```
import React from 'react';

const handleChange = (e) => {
  const index = e.target.selectedIndex;
  const el = e.target.childNodes[index]
  const option =  el.getAttribute('id'); 
  console.log(option)
};

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
        <option value="1-10" id="foo">
          1-10
        </option>
        <option value="2-10" id="zoo">
          2-10
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```